# Problema com a propriedade datakeynames do componente listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Obtenho o seguinte erro ao executar a aplicação:

> Message=DataBinding: 'GestHos.Models.Documentos.FluxoAprovacaoDocumento' does not contain a property with the name 'Setor.Codigo'.

A mensagem de erro se refere ao componente `ListView`, em que a propriedade `DataKeyNames` está setada da seguinte maneira `DataKeyNames="Codigo, Setor.Codigo"`.

O datasource deste `ListView` recebe uma lista de objetos do tipo `FluxoAprovacaoDocumento`.

A classe `FluxoAprovacaoDocumento`, tem uma propriedade do tipo `Setor` que possui uma propriedade chamada `Codigo`.

[image: FluxoAprovacaoDocumento]
[image: Setor]

Como resolver este problema?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstGerenciamento" DataKeyNames="Codigo, Setor.Codigo" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" OnItemCommand="lstGerenciamento_ItemCommand" OnPagePropertiesChanged="lstGerenciamento_PagePropertiesChanged">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" runat="server" id="tblGerenciamento">
                <thead>
                     <tr class="title" runat="server">
                         <th runat="server">&nbsp;</th>
                         <th runat="server" class="text-right">Código</th>
                         <th runat="server">Setor</th>
                         <th runat="server">Tipo de Documento</th>
                         <th runat="server">Status</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Editar" ID="btnEditar" CommandName="Editar" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("AcessoMenu.IncluirAlterar").ToString().Equals("Sim") ? true : false %>'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Ver Detalhes" ID="btnDetalhes" CommandName="Detalhes" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Excluir" ID="btnExcluir" CommandName="Excluir" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("AcessoMenu.IncluirAlterar").ToString().Equals("Sim") ? true : false %>'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1  text-right" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("Codigo") %></td>
            <td class="col-md-3" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# string.Concat(Eval("Setor.Descricao"), " (", Eval("Setor.Sigla"), ")") %></td>
            <td class="col-md-4" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# string.Concat(Eval("TipoDocumento.Descricao"), " (", Eval("TipoDocumento.Sigla"), ")") %></td>
            <td class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle"><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Você tentou algo além disto? Coloque o código todo do listview.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo colocar a parte inicial do código, segue: <asp:ListView ID="lstGerenciamento" DataKeyNames="Codigo, Setor.Codigo" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" OnItemCommand="lstGerenciamento_ItemCommand" OnPagePropertiesChanged="lstGerenciamento_PagePropertiesChanged">

Comment: Não tentei nada além disso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade `DataKeyNames` não suporta a utilização de propriedades de sub-classes. Ou seja, para poder ter esse `Codigo`, terá que ser na classe `FluxoAprovacaoDocumento`.

Pode criar uma propriedade chamado `SetorCodigo` ou algo assim que simplesmente retorna o `Codigo` do `Setor`:

```cs
public int SetorCodigo { 
  get { return Setor.Codigo; }
  set { Setor.Codigo = value; }
}
```